# cmd in explorer file menu is grayed out

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-8.1

Before reading, this is not about adding cmd to 'right click menu'. I have searched a lot! My question is not answered.

I'm using window 8.1 and I was able to run cmd from explorer file menu, but I accidentally removed a registry key and now the cmd is grayed out. When I am in c:\ or d:\, it's still active, but when I go to subfolders, it's disabled (grayed). It makes no different if a file or folder is selected or not.

any solution? does anyone know which registry key controls the contents of file menu in explorer menu bar?

This option already exists in windows 8.1. Normally you can go to file in menu bar and there is an option to open command prompt. Mine was working fine, but now it is grayed out.

I can open cmd by other means.

Answer (score 2):

How I think the problem originated: I ran a registry key that was posted on the internet which adds cmd to the "right click menu". Few days later I decided that I don't want that, so I deleted it, but mistakenly I deleted the registry key in another place.

The registry in the following key controls the right click menu

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell
```

and in the following key, registries do something else.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell
```

I'm guessing that when you right click on a file or folder, you're in shell and when you right click on the background, you're in background\shell.

Anyway, adding the following key revived the grayed command prompt in the explorer's file menu.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd\command
```

with data:

```
cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"
```

if you do the same but add the last two keys to background\shell, you also get cmd when you right click.

Note: adding key is simple, just right click on an existing key (the ones that look like folders) and right click, select new key, and type in a name.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: please take a look at the revision.

Comment: Perfect (with a litle help with the formatting). Well done!